# matlab generate white noise at different decibel

Tags: matlab, audio, whitenoise

I want to generate a white noise of the duration of 200 ms at different dB from 65 to 100. Below an example of my code to generate a 65dB white noise. However when I input a 100 (or any different value). I don't record any difference in intensity.

```
y1 = wgn(200,2,65);
sound(y1)
```

Do you know why? Or what can I do to generate white noises at different intensities?

Comment: What is the range of values in y1?

Comment: `sound` expects the input to be between `-1` and `1`. Values outside that range get clipped

Comment: y1 has actually values between -500 and +500